# Am having difficulties with linked lists

Tags: c, string, struct, linked-list

I am trying to learn linked lists and I am just making this program for practice. It contains several linked lists made from two structs.
Everything from the struct letterLink works fine (typedef ss) 
That linked list simply takes a string of user inputted characters,
prints them backwards, then sorts them alphabetically.

That all works fine.

It’s the other linked list called struct wordLink (typedef sw) that is giving me trouble. I’m attempting to parse the string of letters already entered into a linked list of words base on spaces in the letter string.

Which is created by calling the functions createWordList and appendWord.

Then printed with printWord.

For now don’t worry about the claim of sorting the words alphabetically, in the main function, as I haven't gotten to that function yet.
I’m also aware of a possible bug that might occur in the createWordList function when the user enters more than one space between words, since ptr->letter would be 32 (ascii space) after leaving the inner while loop thius not satisfy the condition of entering back into that loop. I’ll deal with that later.

For now, I’m trying to create the linked list of words, but this will not even print the first word.

Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated, as I just learning this, and can’t figure out why it won’t work.

Thanks. 
I’ll post in full, for compiling purposes, but 
It’s only the last three functions before freeWord in this program that Im grappling with. (createWordList which uses appendWord printed by printWord)

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct linkletter{
    char letter;
    struct linkletter* next;
    } ss;
typedef struct linkword{
    char word[20];
    struct linkword* next;
    } sw;
    ss * createLetter(char);
    sw * createWordList(ss* strt);
    ss * readLetter(void);
    ss * append(ss* end, ss * newLetter);
    sw* appendWord(sw* endWord, sw* newWord);
    void printLetter(ss*);
    void printWord(sw*);
    void freeLetter(ss*);
    void freeWord(sw *wordStart);
    ss * searchLetter(ss* start, char letter);
    ss * insertAtFront(ss* start, ss* newptr);
    ss * reverseLetter(ss* start);
    ss * sortedCopy(ss* start);
    ss * insertIntoSorted(ss* start, ss* newLet);
int main (void){
    ss *start, *backwards, *sorted;
    sw *wordStart;
    printf("enter as many words as you wish separated by spaces:\n (Max 20 letters per word)\n");
    start=readLetter();
    printf("\nyou typed:");
    printLetter(start);
    printf("\nBackwards: ");
    backwards= reverseLetter(start);
    printLetter(backwards);
    printf("\nSorted by Letter: ");
    sorted=sortedCopy(start);
    printLetter(sorted);
    printf("\nYour words in alphetical order:\n");
    wordStart=createWordList(start);
    printWord(wordStart);
    freeLetter(start);
    freeLetter(backwards);
    freeLetter(sorted);
    freeWord(wordStart);







    return 0;
    }

    ss *createLetter(char let){
        ss *ptr;
        ptr=(ss*)malloc(sizeof(ss));
        ptr->letter=let;
        ptr->next=NULL;
        return ptr;
        }   
    ss * readLetter(void){
        char c;
        ss *end, *start, *newLetter;
        start=NULL;
         scanf("%c",&c);
        while(c!='\n'){

            newLetter=createLetter(c);
            if (start==NULL){
                start = newLetter;
                end=start;
                } else {
                    end=append(end,newLetter);
            }
            scanf("%c",&c);
        }
            return start;
    }
    ss *append (ss *end, ss *newLetter){
        end->next=newLetter;
        return end->next;
    }



    void printLetter(ss *start){
        ss* ptr =start;
        while(ptr!=NULL){
            printf("%c",ptr->letter);
            ptr=ptr->next;
            }
            }

    void freeLetter(ss *start){
        ss* ptr=start;
        ss *tmp;
             while(ptr!=NULL){
             tmp=ptr->next;
             free(ptr);
             ptr=tmp;
              }

        }
    ss * searchLetter(ss* start, int number){
        ss* ptr = start;
        while((ptr!=NULL) && (ptr->letter!=number)){
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
            return(ptr);
    }

    ss* insertAtFront(ss* start, ss* newptr){
        newptr->next=start;
        return(newptr);
    }

    ss * reverseLetter(ss* start){
        ss *ptr= start;
        ss *bstart = start;
        ss* newLetter;

        if (start!=NULL){
            bstart=createLetter(start->letter);
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        while(ptr != NULL) {
            newLetter=createLetter(ptr->letter);
            bstart=insertAtFront(bstart, newLetter);
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        return(bstart);
    }

    ss* insertIntoSorted(ss* start, ss* newLet){
        ss* ptr = start;
        ss* prev = NULL;
        while((ptr!=NULL) && (ptr->letter<newLet->letter)){
            prev=ptr;
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        if(prev == NULL) {
            start = insertAtFront(start,newLet);
        } else {
            prev->next = newLet;
            newLet->next = ptr;
        }
        return(start);
    }

    ss* sortedCopy (ss* start){
        ss* ptr = start;
        ss * sortedStart= NULL;
        ss* newLetter;

        if(start!=NULL) {
            sortedStart = createLetter(start->letter);
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        while(ptr!=NULL){
            newLetter = createLetter(ptr->letter);
            sortedStart = insertIntoSorted(sortedStart, newLetter);
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        return(sortedStart);

    }

    sw* createWordList(ss* start){
            ss *ptr=start;
            sw *ptrWord=NULL;
            sw *endWord;
            sw *wordStart=ptrWord;
            int i=0;

        while(ptr->letter!='\n'){
            ptrWord=(sw*)malloc(sizeof(sw));
                 while(ptr->letter!=32) {
                    ptrWord->word[i]=ptr->letter;
                    ptr=ptr->next;
                    i++;
                 }

            ptrWord->next=NULL;
            if(wordStart==NULL){
                wordStart=ptrWord;
                endWord=wordStart;
                } else {
                    appendWord(endWord,wordStart);
                       }
        }   
        return wordStart;
    }   
    sw* appendWord(sw* endWord, sw* newWord){
        endWord->next=newWord;
        return endWord->next;
    }


void printWord(sw *wordStart){
        sw* ptrWord =wordStart;
        while(ptrWord!=NULL){
            printf("%s",ptrWord->word);
            ptrWord=ptrWord->next;
            }
  }


 void freeWord(sw *wordStart){
        ss* ptr=wordStart;
        ss *tmp;
             while(ptr!=NULL){
             tmp=ptr->next;
             free(ptr);
             ptr=tmp;
              }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In `createWordList` you have

```
    while(ptr->letter!='\n'){
        ptrWord=(sw*)malloc(sizeof(sw));
             while(ptr->letter!=32) {
                ptrWord->word[i]=ptr->letter;
                ptr=ptr->next;
                i++;
             }
```

Then

```
        ptrWord->next=NULL;
        if(wordStart==NULL){
            wordStart=ptrWord;
            endWord=wordStart;
        } else {
            appendWord(endWord,wordStart);
        }
```

You are not using the return value of `appendWord` and you append `wordStart` instead of `ptrWord` -- maybe you meant

```
            endWord = appendWord(endWord, ptrWord);
```

Once you hit a space character you stop updating `ptr` since that update is inside

```
while (ptr->letter!=32) {
```

EDITED

Added problem with not updating `ptr` after space characters.

"Every word starts with '\n' because you don't skip past it." was a mistake on my part, I removed it.

Comment: Oh, what the hell? You are right. It isn’t being returned to endWord. My oversight. Didn’t even notice that. Ok, but I don’t understand the part about every word starting with \n. Because at the start of the createWordList function I declare ss *ptr = start. And the start parameter is the first element of the linked list of letters, so shouldn’t ptr-> letter be the first letter of that linked list? Not \n ? I tried EOF too, and it diesn’t work. Either does ‘\0’. So how do i create the condition in the while loop of cycling through all the letters n the ss linked list?

Comment: On a side note, if shift+enter doesn't create a line break for comments on this site, how do  i do  it?

Comment: Instead of while(ptr-> letter != ‘n’) it should be while(ptr!=NULL) since that is how the end of the linked list is reached, but I STILL can’t get it to work. :(

Comment: Updated with `ptr` problem.